# Why do DBS not adapt/tune their buffer sizes automatically?

Tags: database, size, buffer, performance

Not sure whether there isn't a DBS that does and whether this is indeed a useful feature, but:
There are a lot of suggestions on how to speed up DB operations by tuning buffer sizes. One example is importing Open Street Map data (the planet file) into a Postgres instance. There is a tool called osm2pgsql (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) for this purpose and also a guide that suggests to adapt specific buffer parameters for this purpose.
In the final step of the import, the database is creating indexes and (according to my understanding when reading the docs) would benefit from a huge maintenance_work_mem whereas during normal operation, this wouldn't be too useful.
This thread http://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-general@postgresql.org/msg119245.html in the contrary suggests a large maintenance_work_mem would not make too much sense during final index creation.
Ideally (imo), the DBS should know best what buffers size combination it could profit most given a limited size of total buffer memory.
So, are there some good reasons why there isn't a built-in heuristic that is able to adapt the buffer sizes automatically according to the current task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the same as with any forecasting software. Just because something happened historically doesn't mean it will happen again. Also, you need to complete a task in order to fully analyze how you should have done it more efficient. Problem is that the next task is not necessarily anything like the previously completed task. So if your import routine needed 8gb of memory to complete, would it make sense to assign each read-only user 8gb of memory? The other way around wouldn't work well either.

In leaving this decision to humans, the database will exhibit performance characteristics that aren't optimal for all cases, but in return, let's us (the humans) optimize each case individually (if like to).

Another important aspect is that most people/companies value reliable and stable levels over varying but potentially better levels. Having a high cost isn't as big a deal as having large variations in cost. This is of course not true all the times as entire companies are based around the fact the once in a while hit that 1%.

Modern databases already make some effort into adapting itself to the tasks presented, such as increasingly more sofisticated query optimizers. At least Oracle have the option to keep track of some of the measures that are influencing the optimizer decisions (cost of single block read which will vary with the current load).

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* would be it is awfully hard to get the knobs right by adaptive means. First you will have to query the machine for a lot of unknowns like how much RAM it has available - but also the unknown "what do you expect to run on the machine in addition".

Barring that, by setting a `max_mem_usage` parameter only, the problem is how to make a system which

- adapts well to most typical loads.
- Don't have odd pathological problems with some loads.
- is somewhat comprehensible code without error.

For postgresql however the answer could also be

- Nobody wrote it yet because other stuff is seen as more important.
- *You* didn't write it yet.